# Winner, Winner, Chicken Dinner

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

Though they're here in disguise,
(Maybe due to their fame)
They've brought joy to my eyes.
Can you tell me my name?

---

**V**enus from the U.S.
**P**recipitation Dude
**V**ehicles Ablaze
**S**omething Sailed above the Asylum
**E**namored William

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your name is

> Oscar

Each of the following are

> Synonyms for film names that have won the academy award for Best Picture

Venus from the U.S.

> American Beauty

Precipitation Dude

> Rain Man

Vehicles Ablaze

> Chariots of Fire

Something Sailed above the Asylum

> One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest

Enamored William

> Shakespeare in Love

Then,

> Take the first letter of each actual film name (as indicated by the bold in the question), and you get an anagram of Oscar.

Comment: Nicely Done, and very specific in your explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Is it:

> Actors

Though they're here in disguise,
(Maybe due to their fame)

> Actors play characters, not themselves

They've brought joy to my eyes.
Can you tell me my name?

> Watching good movies make people happy

Venus from the U.S.

> American Beauty

Precipitation Dude

> Rain Man

Vehicles Ablaze

> Blazing Saddles

Something Sailed above the Asylum

> One Flew Over the Cuckoos Nest

Enamored William

> Shakespeare in Love

Comment: Close.. not "actors."  Looking for a **name**.